# What unique means here (hashover script)?

Tags: php

I'm trying to implement [hashover](http://tildehash.com/?page=hashover)
script.
I followed the instructions but I am getting this error:

> **HashOver:** The variable values in /hashover/scripts/secrets.php need to be UNIQUE.

What unique means? Above my `secret.php` encryption line

```
// Unique 8 to 32 character encryption key
$encryption_key     = 'e10adc3949ba59abbe56e057f20f883e';
```

I also tried:

```
// Unique 8 to 32 character encryption key
$encryption_key     = '12345678';
```

Same error with both lines.

Answer (score 2):

We can see on [hashover.php](https://github.com/jacobwb/hashover/blob/master/hashover.php)

```
// Exit if encryption key, notification email, or administrative nickname or password set to defaults
if ($encryption_key == '8CharKey' || $notification_email == 'example@example.com' || $admin_nickname == 'admin' || $admin_password == 'passwd') {
    exit(jsAddSlashes('<b>HashOver:</b> The variable values in /hashover/scripts/secrets.php need to be UNIQUE.', 'single'));
}
```

That mean `$admin_nickname` should not be `'admin'`, `$notification_email` should not be `'example@example.com'` etc etc. Make sure you change all of this values

Comment: @ThomasTuur Maybe contact the author? From his website: "I invite you to contact me for whatever you may wish to ask me".

Comment: I did! And Jacob is a great guy. He solve the issue and will post a 1.01 version.

Comment: can you please share 1.01 version. @ThomasTuur